# How do I consistently find the PID of a program OR how do I send the kill shortcut to my terminal from a C script?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, pid

**I'm answering my own question here because all of the other threads talking about this gave generally inefficient solutions to this problem[refer to title].**

The most logical way to find the PID of a program is with getpid. However for some reason getpid command always gives you the PID that is two numbers behind the actual program ID it's about to be assigned. I'm sure someone more familiar with the linux kernel will be sure to explain why I'm an idiot in the comments below, so the reasoning for the -2 pid is probably down there.

Anyway, here's a reverse engineered c script(from MTU) that gives you the PID of the program.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>

void  main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    char fetch[50];
    pid = getpid();
    int pid2=pid+2;
    sprintf(fetch, "echo hello world! my PID is %d", pid2);
    system(fetch);
}
```

Comment: The reason for the +2 lies in the process tree - `system` will fork and exec a shell, and that will run your command. However. this is _really_ fragile. Whenever `pid+1` or `pid+2` is already in use, it'll break and kill the wrong thing. So, what process _exactly_ do you need to kill from where?

Comment: `getpid` returns the PID of the current process. Do you mean that `pid+2` happens to be the PID of the shell or `echo` process started with `system()`? Please [edit] your question and write a clear specification of the problem you want to solve, then write your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> However for some reason getpid command always gives you the PID that is two numbers behind the actual program ID it's about to be assigned.

Well, `getpid` returns the PID of the *current* process.
How can it return the PID of a new process that doesn't exist yet? How could it possibly know?

The current process has a process ID. When you call `system`, it creates a child process, with its own process ID. Presumably the child process then creates another child to execute the command you passed to `system`.

By default the first child's PID will be the current process PID + 1. And the second child's PID will be the current process PID + 2. However, if either of those IDs are already in use (or you hit the maximum value of a `pid_t` and wrap around), this brittle logic will break completely.

If you want to get a child process' PID, call `fork` directly:

```
pid_t childpid = fork();
if (childpid < 0) {
  perror("failed to fork");
  exit(1);
}
if (childpid == 0) {
  /* this path executes in the child process */
  exec_command_in_child();
} else {
  /* this path executes in the parent */
  wait_or_kill_or_something(childpid);
}
```